# Are there alternate OSes for the click-wheel iPods?

Tags: ipod

The firmware on the click-wheel iPod is very simple and doesn't have a lot of "extra" features. It also doesn't allow you to drop music on it; it has to go through iTunes. Are there alternate OSes for the click-wheel iPods?

Comment: If you downvote, ***please*** comment and tell why you downvoted!! A downvote is useless if you don't give a reason for your downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternate OS is [Rockbox](http://www.rockbox.org/). It is a free firmware replacement that works on many music players. Rockbox supports:

> iPod 1g through 5.5g, iPod Mini, iPod Nano 1g and iPod Nano 2g

One downside to Rockbox is that you have to make your iPod a Windows formatted partition on a Windows computer.

There are many different [themes for Rockbox](http://themes.rockbox.org/). Here's an example of just one:
[image: Rockbox Karma]

Answer (score 2):

There's another alternative operating system for click wheel iPods called [iPodLinux](http://ipodlinux.org). Here's the iPodLinux status: http://www.ipodlinux.org/Project_Status/